# How to define events with JQuery using class or ids selectors before element has been loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

As most of us know, once an element has been loaded it is possible to attach an event to it by simply using the normal JQuery events.

The question is, what if I want to create a specific event, and define that an element with a specific class or id, will get that event automatically when they are loaded?

For example:

I have a function that checks whether the input that has been entered is numeric only, and allows only numbers to be entered inside an input.

To do that I add the class "numeric" to the input element.

Normally I would just run a script right after with JQuery or just by using the onkeypressed DOM event to attach that function to it.

However, let's assume I have an ajax request that attaches a new from page, with the class numeric in the proper input elements.

Using the script again using the same class selector will result in the event run 2 times for elements that were loaded earlier.. And for every time I run that script it will add that event over and over...

What I do now, is I used the "unbind" first, and then reattach the event to all elements, and it is working perfectly! But I am looking for more elegant solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the [**.on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with event delegation

**Syntax**

```
$(parent-selector).on(event,target-selector,callback);
```

***Note:** The parent-selector must be parent element which is present in the DOM while binding the event, generally people use `document` and `body`, but for the performance you must have the **nearest parent possible** to the target*

**Example**

```
$(document).on("click",".button",function(){
    alert("Button Clicked");
});
```

Comment: This information is most useful.

The extra performance notice is very important and I might have never know it unless you added it so thank you very much for that extra.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function to attach event handlers for elements that do not exist.

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".numeric", function(){
   //do something
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/T34Ph/

Comment: @JacobCohen Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: I wish I could mark 2 right answers, since you and Rohit both gave me the right answer in a very short time!
This is most helpful information and correct, but I'll mark Rohit's since he answered first. I did mark your answer as useful though.